# Using Eigen C++ library on ARM Zynq ( baremetal )

Tags: c++, gcc, eigen, zynq

After failing to cross compile GNU Scientific library for Zynq baremetal ( [Cross compile GNU Scientific Library for ARM Zynq ( baremetal )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074957/cross-compile-gnu-scientific-library-for-arm-zynq-baremetal) ), I tried to use Eigen C++ instead.

So i download it then unzip it and include it's header like below

```
-I/home/wizard/Desktop/eigen
```

The code works fine on my PC ( which is x64 Ubuntu ) But as soon as i change the compiler from gcc to arm-xilinx-eabi-gcc & g++ to arm-xilinx-eabi-g++ the code gives me the following errors :

```
invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'const int32_t* {aka const long int*}' [-fpermissive]   test4       line 244, external location: /home/wizard/Desktop/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/NEON/PacketMath.h   C/C++ Problem
invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'const int32_t* {aka const long int*}' [-fpermissive]   test4       line 247, external location: /home/wizard/Desktop/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/NEON/PacketMath.h   C/C++ Problem
invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'const int32_t* {aka const long int*}' [-fpermissive]   test4       line 259, external location: /home/wizard/Desktop/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/NEON/PacketMath.h   C/C++ Problem
invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'const int32_t* {aka const long int*}' [-fpermissive]   test4       line 260, external location: /home/wizard/Desktop/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/NEON/PacketMath.h   C/C++ Problem
invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int32_t* {aka long int*}' [-fpermissive] test4       line 265, external location: /home/wizard/Desktop/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/NEON/PacketMath.h   C/C++ Problem
invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int32_t* {aka long int*}' [-fpermissive] test4       line 268, external location: /home/wizard/Desktop/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/NEON/PacketMath.h   C/C++ Problem
invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int32_t* {aka long int*}' [-fpermissive] test4       line 309, external location: /home/wizard/Desktop/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/NEON/PacketMath.h   C/C++ Problem
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Well it's probably a C library, so compile it as C code using `gcc` not `g++`. If you need to use it in your C++ code, then compile it, link it as usual and include it with `extern "C"` idiom.

Comment: @tambre I probably didn't get your point but "Eigen" is a **C++ template library**. Plus i try to compile it with gcc but didn't worked :(

Comment: Well i don't know why but version 2 of Eigen worked like a charm !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally able to solve the problem. Refer to https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=138964 "Compiling Eigen3 on Zynq baremetal" for solution.